# Finding the VIF of parameters in base R

Tags: r, statistics, modeling

I'm doing some multivariate linear modeling currently and need to find the variance inflation factor (vif) for each of my parameters.  I usually use the `car`package, but I am presently not able to use external packages for R.

Is there a way to calculate vif in base R? And if there is how am I to go about calculating it?

Comment: Write you own function (based on `car:::vif.default`)

Answer (score 3):

Just copy the source code of `car:::vif.default` into your own source code.  A quick glance suggests that the function doesn't contain any references to unexported `car` functions (which would have to be copied in addition), so it should just work as is.